# How to differentiate between 2 Arabic letters in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, unicode

In Arabic there are 2 letters that pronounced the same but written differently

The letter ة

and the letter ت

I wanted to replace the letter ة with another letter ه

Now I used this

```
Update MyTable
SET MyColumn = Replace ( MyColumn, N'ة' , N'ه' )
```

But ended with replacing every letter that has ة or ت to be replaced with ه

How can I tell SQL Server to replace only ة  Not ت ?

Comment: Try a binary collation, e.g. `REPLACE( MyColumn COLLATE Arabic_BIN, N'ة' COLLATE Arabic_BIN, N'ه' COLLATE Arabic_BIN)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify a `COLLATE` clause with a binary collation to use the code points of the exact characters to be searched/replaced:

```
UPDATE dbo.MyTable
SET MyColumn = REPLACE( MyColumn COLLATE Arabic_BIN, N'ة' COLLATE Arabic_BIN, N'ه' COLLATE Arabic_BIN);
```